# why camera sensor fit auto,horizontal and vertical FOV different in resolustion x<y?

Tags: camera

Theoretically when resolution x>y（horizontal photo）  it should select horizontal of sensor fit, auto fov = horizontal fov. when resolution x<y（vertical photo）  it should select vertical of sensor fit, auto fov =vertical fov. but In fact when resolution x<y auto  is different vertical fov, there is 3 fov! why? Is it a code error?[image]

Comment: Hello ! Could you add a bit more info, like which add-on you're using and what it's supposed to do.

Comment: the addon is photopgraher 4  but it doesn't matter, you can manully input photo resolution,if x>y is landscape mode .if y>x is portrait mode, but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the sensors fit. if y > x sensor fit have three diffenret FOV. why?